# what is the problem with itemdatabound event in listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am getting the following error  during itemdataboundevent of a listview.

**Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:** CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemType' to 'System.Data.DataRowView'

**Source Error:**

```
   Line 91:             CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkFocusArea");
Line 92:            
Line 93:             System.Data.DataRowView rowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)e.Item.ItemType; 
Line 94:             
Line 95:         }
```

my code behind for itembound event is

```
protected void lvFocusArea_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkFocusArea");

        System.Data.DataRowView rowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)e.Item.ItemType; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong property. Cast first to `ListViewDataItem` and use `DataItem` instead of `ItemType`:

**C#**

```
ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
System.Data.DataRowView rowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)dataItem.DataItem;
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim dataItem As ListViewDataItem = CType(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)
Dim rowView As System.Data.DataRowView = CType(dataItem.DataItem, DataRowView)
```

Comment: I am using Visual web developer express edition.There is no intellisense for e.Item.DataItem.

Comment: I forgot you have to cast to ListViewDataItem first. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks to the modified solution

Comment: I noticed you unchecked this as the accepted answer. The solution didn't work for you?